# Getting Error - EPERM : operation not permitted

Tags: next.js

Getting below error while building next project :-

uncaughtException [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\prash\New folder (7)\practopm.next\trace'] {
errno: -4048,
code: 'EPERM',
syscall: 'open',
path: 'C:\Users\prash\New folder (7)\practopm\.next\trace'
}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vqa0v.png)

To be able to build next project

Comment: Please post the code as 4xt, not a screenshot.